# How to stretch image in img tag larger than its natural size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

If I have a N pixel by N pixel image, how do I use CSS/JS/jQuery to make it fill a say... 2N pixel by 2N pixel space?

Details: I'm more of a back-end developer but I'm currently implementing a "zoom in" functionality where you click on an image and it then replaces it with a larger image that then resizes the `<div>` the `<img>` tag is in to take up more space and effectively 'zoom in' (or really just unsquish a large image).

What I need to do (UX): While waiting for the larger image to load I want the user to be able to still 'zoom' but since the larger image has yet to load they would just get a grainy version of the image until it is then replaced with the higher resolution image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `width` and `height` attributes of the `IMG` element accordingly.

Alternatively, use CSS properties of the same name. Note that in CSS, `width` and `height` must have units (for images, it is typically `px`).

Comment: Yea I was wondering why I was having trouble with such a seemingly simple task (even for a backend dev.) turns out the guy who constructed this used vh and vw instead of pixels or % for unit of size, and I guess that won't stretch an image past its natural resolution.

Answer (score 2):

This may work:

```
var img = $("img");
$("div").click(function()
{
    img.css("width",img.width()*2);
    img.css("height",img.height()*2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I put something together using `toggleClass`, `transform: scale` and `transition`.

Clicking the image will resize it in one second, meanwhile the larger image is loaded. It will then either pick the point when the transition has ended or in case it takes longer to load the image than the duration of the transition, append the image when it has finished loading. Switching *during* the transition would be overly complicated, I tried that at first. Also put in a check with `addClass` on the parent so it will only load the larger image once and not on each toggle to enlarge.

[**Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNPrjB?editors=001)

```js
$('div').click(function() {

  var div = $(this),
  img = div.find('img'),
  path = img[0].src.replace('.jpg', ''),
  ended, loaded;

  img.toggleClass('zoom');

  if (!div.hasClass('large')) {

    div.addClass('large');

    var big = new Image();
    big.src = path + '_large.jpg';

    img.one('transitionend', function() {

      ended = true;
      if (loaded) replaceImage(big);
    });

    $(big).one('load', function() {

      loaded = true;
      if (ended) replaceImage(big);
    });
  }

function replaceImage(grand) {

  if (img.hasClass('zoom')) $(grand).addClass('zoom');

  div.html(grand);
}
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
}

div img {
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s linear;
  transition: transform 1s linear;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
  transform-origin: center top;
}

.zoom {
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <img src="//www.anony.ws/i/2015/11/19/yosemite.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

It takes the path from the original image and adds `_large` to it. So in this scenario the images would have to be in the same folder and basically named the same apart from that extra extension.

Edited to make sure the `zoom` class only gets applied when the original image also has it. This takes care of a glitch when the user clicks multiple times before the large version was loaded.